# Error al usar struct con indice 0 y medicion de un struct dinamico

Tags: c, struct, lógica

Estoy creando un codigo que calcula distancias entre puntos de un plano cartesiano, y deberia de sacar las distancias menores entre ellas, uso un ***struct dinamico*** con malloc para guardar los datos:

```
struct puntos
{
      int idPunto;
      float valorX;
      float valorY;
      float Modulo;
      float Angulo;

};
```

La creacion y declaracion del struct es esta:

```
struct puntos *punto;
punto=(struct puntos*)malloc(sizeof(struct puntos)*aux1);
```

El codigo para encontrar las distancias menores es este:

```
    min = 1000000;
    puns = fopen("resultadosDeDistancias.txt","w+");
    unsigned int tamanio = sizeof(punto);

    for(i=0;i<tamanio;i++){
        for(j=0;j<tamanio;j++){
            if(j != i){
                dis = distancia(punto[i].valorX,punto[i].valorY, punto[j].valorX, punto[j].valorY);
                if(dis<min){
                    min = dis;
                    dis2=j+1;
                }
                else{
                    min = min;
                }
            }
        }
        fprintf(puns, "Para el punto %d, el punto %d es el que a menor distancia se encuentra: %.3f u\n",i+1,dis2,min);
        min = 1000000;
    }
    fclose(puns);
```

El struct punto lo puedo llenar de manera manual o con numeros al azar, cree una funcion para que con rand me puedan dar numeros float negativos:

```
for(i=0; i<aux1; i++){
            punto[i].idPunto = i+1;
            punto[i].valorX = numeror(200);
            punto[i].valorY = numeror(200);
            punto[i].Modulo = modulo(punto[i].valorX, punto[i].valorY);
            punto[i].Angulo = angulop(punto[i].valorX, punto[i].valorY);

            fprintf(arch,"%d\t", punto[i].idPunto);
            fprintf(arch,"\t%.3f\t", punto[i].valorX);
            fprintf(arch,"\t%.3f\t", punto[i].valorY);
            fprintf(arch,"\t%.3f\t", punto[i].Modulo);
            fprintf(arch,"\t%.3f\n", punto[i].Angulo);
        }
```

***aux1*** en una variable que le pido al usuario

Al crear una lista de 10 puntos aleatoriamente, el programa me arroja resultados correctos con los parametros indicados:

1 -19.000 184.000 184.978 95.896

2 -67.000 -7.000 67.365 185.964

etc

Al tratar de calcular las distancias me arroja resultados erroneos, solo calcula distancias de 8 puntos y el punto numero 1 siempre arroja 10000 porque calcula distancias con el punto 0 que no existe

No estoy seguro si es problema de logica o estoy colocando algun comando erroneamente.

Comment: Por favor, presenta un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema. Tu código no se puede probar. No hay datos de prueba, el array `punto` no está inicializado en ningún sitio, ...

Comment: También minimiza el código al necesario. Si el problema está en el resultado de la función *distancia*, el bucle de fuera no es necesario, solo decir qué estás pasando a la llamada que da el resultado incorrecto (y qué resultado encuentras). Si el problema es que se hacen llamadas que no tocan, la implementación de *distancia* no parece ser muy relevante.

Comment: @eferion ya lo corregi, espero asi la pregunta este bien formulada

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes. No se puede copiar texto desde una imagen. En segundo lugar, no muestras cómo creas y rellenas el array `punto`

Comment: @eferion ya lo corregi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos a hacer una sencilla prueba:

```
char p;
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

printf("%d %d", sizeof(p), sizeof(ptr));
```

Este código arroja el siguente resultado:

```
1 8
```

¿Cómo es que `ptr` devuelve el valor 8? si tiene 100 elementos!!!

El problema que tienes aquí es que estás asumiendo que `sizeof` va a conocer el tamaño de la reserva de memoria apuntada por `ptr` y no es así. `sizeof` te devuelve **cuanto ocupa la variable**. Da la casualidad que en 64 bits un puntero ocupa 64 bits, que son 8 bytes y ese es el valor que devuelve `sizeof`. De hecho `sizeof` es una función especial que se evalúa en tiempo de compilación, es decir, en el binario final la llamada a `sizeof` se ha reemplazado por un número.

Si vemos el código ensamblado generado por el código fuente anterior, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
sub     rsp, 32
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
cdqe
mov     rdi, rax
call    malloc
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
mov     eax, 8
leave
ret
```

Si atendemos a la antepenúltima operación vemos un 8 literal, ese es el valor que devuelve la función.

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://godbolt.org/z/16MjqE).

Si pruebas a cambiar `ptr` por `char` verás como ese 8 cambia por un 1 (y es lo único que va a cambiar). Puedes probar con otros tipos si quieres.

Vale, pues ya hemos visto que la operación que haces para calcular cuántos elementos hay en el array es incorrecto. Tienes que hacer llegar el valor de `aux1` al bucle que calcula las distancias:

```
for(i=0;i<aux1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<aux1;j++){
```

**Nota** Yo no usaría variables con nombres tan generalistas. Es mejor usar nombres que indiquen realmente la funcionalidad de la variable, como `numeroPuntos`. Te ahorrará muchos dolores de cabeza.

Con esto entiendo que el cálculo de las distancias te empezará a dar resultados normales. Sin embargo hay otros detalles a mejorar.

**Código innecesario**

Lo primero sería eliminar código innecesario:

```
else{
    min = min;
}
```

Este `else` no hace absolutamente nada. ¿Para qué vas a querer asignar a una variable el valor que ya tiene almacenado? ¿Temes que se pierda si no lo refrescas continuamente? Lo dicho, el `else` sobra.

**Números mágicos**

Por otro lado, ese 100000 que usas como valor de inicio de la distancia ... esos valores escritos a piñón se llaman números mágicos. Son mágicos porque solo tu sabes por qué estás usando ese valor y no otro. Si las condiciones cambian (en este caso que los puntos puedan estar más alejados unos de otros), el programa podría fallar y no sabrías el motivo. Es convieniente evitar el uso de números mágicos.

En C tienes a tu disposición la cabecera [`limits.h`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) la cual contiene información sobre los tipos básicos del lenguaje. Aquí puedes encontrar, por ejemplo, la macro `INT_MAX` que te devuelve el valor máximo que va a entrar en un `int`.

**Ámbito de las variables**

Estás cogiendo el mal hábito de alargar innecesariamente la vida de las variables. La vida de una variable debe ser la mínima imprescindible.

Si, por ejemplo, tienes 3 bucles consecutivos, no pasa absolutamente nada si cada uno usa su propia variable de iteración, aunque todas se llamen `i`. El problema de alargar la vida de las variables es que puedes caer en la tentación de reutilizarlas. Al reutilizarlas existe el riesgo de que se nos *olvide* inicializarlas antes de usarlas de nuevo y entonces el programa empezará a dar valores extraños ... con la pérdida de años de vida que conlleva bucear por el código en busca del error.

Es decir, es preferible esto:

```
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
{ printf("%d", i); }

for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
{ printf("%d", i); }

for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
{ printf("%d", i); }
```

A esto

```
int i;

for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
{ printf("%d", i); }

for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
{ printf("%d", i); }

for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
{ printf("%d", i); }
```

De hecho puedes comprobar [aquí](https://godbolt.org/z/j8qv8e) como el ensamblado que se genera es **exactamente el mismo**, es decir, no hay penalizaciones de rendimiento ni otros problemas que tanto atemorizan a los programadores.

A modo de prueba, pongo el ensamblado del primer ejemplo hasta el primer bucle:

```
    test    edi, edi
    jle     .L10
    push    r12
    mov     r12d, edi
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    xor     ebx, ebx
.L3:
    mov     esi, ebx
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     ebp, ebx
    call    printf
    lea     ebx, [rbx+1]
    cmp     r12d, ebx
    jne     .L3
    xor     ebx, ebx
```

Y ahora lo mismo pero para el segundo ejemplo:

```
    test    edi, edi
    jle     .L23
    push    r12
    mov     r12d, edi
    push    rbp
    push    rbx
    xor     ebx, ebx
.L16:
    mov     esi, ebx
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     ebp, ebx
    call    printf
    lea     ebx, [rbx+1]
    cmp     r12d, ebx
    jne     .L16
    xor     ebx, ebx
```

Puedes dedicarle todo el tiempo que quieras a buscar las diferencias, no las hay:

- `.L10` y `.L23` son las etiquetas que hacen el return en cada caso
- `.L3` y `.L16` son las etiquetas que ejecutan el primer bucle de cada función

**Asunciones**

Nota que no deberías asumir tan alegremente el valor de `dis2` (no se por qué esa variable se llama `dis2` cuando no almacena distancias sino índices). El caso es que el valor correcto lo deberías buscar en la estructura `puntos`:

```
struct puntos
{
      int idPunto; // <<--- AQUI
      float valorX;
      float valorY;
      float Modulo;
      float Angulo;
};
```

Así pues, `dis2` debería definirse así:

```
dis2 = punto[j].idPunto;
```

O, mejor aún, podrías copiar el punto en concreto o apuntar a él. Esto te permitiría recuperar varios valores del elemento `B`. Por cierto, nota que en este código he ido aplicando los cambios que te he comentado hasta la fecha:

```
for(int i=0;i<numeroPuntos;i++){
    int min = INT_MAX;
    struct puntos * puntoB = NULL;
    for(int j=0;j<numeroPuntos;j++){
        if(j != i){
            int dis = distancia(punto[i].valorX,punto[i].valorY, punto[j].valorX, punto[j].valorY);
            if(dis<min){
                min = dis;
                puntoB = &punto[j];
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(puns, "Para el punto %d, el punto %d es el que a menor distancia se encuentra: %.3f u\n",punto[i].idPunto,puntoB->idPunto,min);
    // min = 1000000; <<--- Esto ya no es necesario
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya he intentado cambiar varias de las cosas que me recomendaste pero ahora me aparece un error *** Segmentation fault (core dumped)*** al hacer tu codigo.

Comment: tambien queria aclarar que necesito calcular el tamaño del struct porque en un futuro necesito recuperar puntos de un archivo y ahi no voy a tener un valor de numeroPuntos entonces no sabria que hacer

Comment: @ErikAlcantara para el números de puntos puedes guardar un entero al inicio del archivo con dicho valor. También puedes usar `realloc` para ir incrementando la reserva de memoria según vayas leyendo los puntos

Comment: @ErikAlcantara el error del core dumped es por acceder a memoria que no te pertenece. Puede ser que estés leyendo fuera de los límites del array. No tengo tu código actual y no puedo saber el origen. Quizás se merezca una nueva pregunta o quizás debas aprovechar para aprender a usar los depuradores de código

Comment: crees que podamos seguir hablando la verdad creo que mi codigo no esta muy bien hecho pero mañana es la fecha de entrega y aun tengo varios problemas. creo que stackoverflow tiene una funcion para mensajeria instantanea

Comment: @ErikAlcantara existen unas salas de chat, ignoro si necesitas un mínimo de reputación para entrar en ellas. El caso es que StackOverflow no está para ayudarte únicamente a ti, la idea es que las respuestas le puedan servir a más gente. Usar un chat para resolver tus dudas personales está fuera del ámbito de este sitio y quizás debiera ser hasta un servicio remunerado (los profesores no dan clase gratis ni los mecánicos arreglan sin ver dinero de por medio)

Comment: @ErikAlcantara en cualquier caso puedes crear preguntas nuevas. Si las elaboras correctamente seguro que obtienes algunas respuestas

Comment: ok, disculpa estoy algo desesperado

Comment: @ErikAlcantara no te disculpes, no has ofendido a nadie. Solo intento que entiendas cómo funciona este sitio y el valor del tiempo que le dedicamos a nuestros aportes